# Path can't find Python or packages

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, git-bash

I'm new to Windows and using the command line. I'm having issues with how the path works.

I installed Python 3 using Anaconda on a Windows 10, and I'm using a virtual environment that doesn't seem to recognize python.

```html
$ python --version
bash: python: command not found
```

In the command line, Python is installed, but many packages like Flask and Pandas also aren't being recognized. I've used pip install, which works correctly

```html
$ pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\dta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\dta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\dta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in c:\users\dta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in c:\users\dta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from flask) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\dta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask) (1.0)
twisted 18.7.0 requires PyHamcrest>=1.9.0, which is not installed.
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But then running a program with either of those packages doesn't work and I get a result like this one:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

It seems like the path is set, but there's some issue with the command line recognizing it correctly. I've uninstalled and then reinstalled Python and made sure to check the box ‘Add Python to PATH’ during the installation but nothing has worked. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: try `python3 --version` and see if it works. `python` only should link to python3 but just to be sure, use python3.

Comment: Nope, no luck with that.

Comment: Sorry just to confirm: have you activate the virtual environment? I expect to see (`venv_name`) before `$` in your console unless there's some oddity here.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't include it, but I named it (myenv) and it is showing up correctly.

Comment: @Amber_Luk Do you use anaconda 3 because it is easier to install? My experience with python3 on windows is that...Installation without Anaconda actually makes my life easier. BTW you need to ensure that python is in your environment variable path. And to edit your environment variable, you need to have Administrator rights.

Comment: To be honest, I've never tried to install python without anaconda. And I've made sure that python is in my environment variable path, but it's still not working and I'm not sure why. I am an administrator BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely do not have Anaconda on your Path. Try:

```
echo %PATH%
```

if [Mini|Ana]conda is not there, open Anaconda CMD. Start typing on wundows Start Menu. In that, `conda` command should work. Type `where conda`. It show where conda is: then do something like

```
SETX PATH “%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Scripts;%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3”
```

This will set anaconda to Path. Close and Restart CMD

If you have different environments, try

```
conda env list
```

To activate your environment:

```
conda activate environmentName
```

Remember to use conda install ... over pip as it deals with upgrades and downgrade for compatibility issues.

if Anaconda is there, then you must have another Python their too that comes before Anaconda. That will be selected over Anaconda, unless you rearrange that Anaconda comes first before it.

If you do not want that, you can simply create an environment:

```
conda create -n awesome python=3.7
```

Then activate it and install your packages there:

```
conda activate awesome
conda install flask
python -V # Python 3.7
```

To see where Python looks for packages do:

```
python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
```

See where it is looking for packages.

Comment: Do you know why setx PATH “%PATH%;c:\users\dta\anaconda3\scripts;c:\users\dta\anaconda3” returns 
setx: command not found

Comment: Yes, SET will temporarily add tools while SETX add the permanently. So we concatenation your %Path% with Anaconda tools. Between another issue could be you have another Python on your Path that comes before Anaconda. That will be selected over Anacondas

Comment: Updated my answer with more info.

Comment: I created an environment precisely for that reason using these commands:
$ conda create -n myenv
$ source activate my env
$ conda install flask
Everything worked up to this point and when I tried running a script that imports flask, I received a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'

Comment: Try > where python, that is =>which python in Linux. See what it gives you! What do you see when you do python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"?

Comment: In the (myenv) virtual environment, I get "which: command not found", and in  git bash I get this path: /c/Users/DTA/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0/python. It also doesn't recognize python as a command in the virtual environment.

Comment: In your environment can you do> conda list, see if Flask is there!

Comment: Use "where" not "which" in Windows. Btw did you add python=3.7 while creating your environment?

Comment: Yup, it mentions flask version 1.0.2. And also where wasn't recognized as a command either.

Comment: Try restart your PC!

Comment: Btw in git bash, you have a totally different path, as you are in Linux-ish world! Now I am lost, did you install anaconda in git-bash?

Comment: Ok, so I restarted, used $ source activate my env and then $ conda install flask. I tried running my script again and now it can't find the module 'pandas'.

Comment: Btw: did you install Linux Anaconda in git-bash? It appears that you are in git-bash, and not windows as you use “source activate ...” ;) why did you not say that ;) in git-bash, conda list | grep pandas

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what I'm doing. $ conda list showed that I did have flask. Then I conda installed pandas and ran the script again and it finally worked. I guess my main question is, if I installed python with anaconda, why do I need to conda install flask, pandas, etc.?

Comment: In git-bash, you have python and python3! When you did pip install ... you actually used python 2.7 ;) using conda, you ensure that you are installing packages in the right place ;)

Comment: I see, ok. Thank you so much!